# Passing constructor parameter to Nunit Base class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a base class to generate duplicated test methods.

```
public interface IService1 { }
public interface IService2: IService1 { }

[TestFixture]
public abstract class MyBase
{
    private readonly IService1 service;

    protected MyBase(IService1 service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [Test]
    public void test1()
    {
        //service.callmethod
    }
}
```

I have implemented this base class to another test class like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTest:MyBase
{
    private IService2 service;

    [SetUp]
    public void setup()
    {
        service = A.Fake<IService2>();
    }

    public MyTest(IService2 service) : base(service)
    {
    }
}
```

This gives error: **No suitable constructor was found**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[TestFixture]` attribute on `MyBase` shouldn't be there.  As an abstract class, it can't be created, so it's not really a fixture.

NUnit only knows how to call the default constructor for your class, so your test fixtures should have default constructors.  With your example code, where are you expecting the `service` passed into the `MyTest` constructor to come from?

An alternate approach that can be used to achieve a similar thing is to delegate the creation of object to child classes from the abstract parent.  So you end up with something like this:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    [Test]
    public void test1()
    {
        GetService().callmethod();
    }

    public abstract IService1 GetService();
}


[TestFixture]
public class MyTest:MyBase
{
    private IService2 service;


    [SetUp]
    public void setup()
    {
        service = A.Fake<IService2>();
    }

    public override IService1 GetService()
    {
        return service;
    }
}
```

So the child class implements the abstract method `GetService` to allow the parent class to fetch the service object reference it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but to specifically answer your question:

#### "Passing constructor parameter to Nunit Base class"

... and to do this in NUnit style:

TestBase.cs

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestBase
{
    public string Browser { get; set; }
    public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
    public TestBase( string _browser){ this.Browser = _browswer }

    [SetUp]
    public Setup(){
        Driver = SeleniumExtension.GetDriver(Browser);
    }
}
```

MyTests.cs

```
[TestFixture("Chrome", "IE", "Firefox")]
class MyTests : TestBase
{
     public MyTests(string _browser) : base(_browser) { }

     [Test]
     public void Test_001(){
          Driver.Goto("https://www.google.com");
     }
}
```

Rebuild.
In your test explorer you will now see testfixture variants of Test_001 including all three types of tests, Chrome, IE and Firefox. 
You also have access to any class or variables you might need in your tests as with normal inheritance.
Cleans up the tests a lot.
 HTH someone!